# who ever launches the process from IBM BPM Process portal should land immediately to first human task so the user doesn't have to claim it explicitly

Tags: business-process-management, business-process

When we launch/initiate a process from process portal in IBM BPM, first human task of the process appears in the work (task inbox). But that user has to claim it explicitly to work on the task and that is a problem in my case.
What I want to achieve is: who ever launches the process from portal should land immediately to first human task so the user doesn't have to claim it explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is unintuitive and poorly documented. Fortunately, it is very easy to do. It's one of those things that everyone "just knows" and is, by far, everyone's first question when using the product. Here's the trick:
If you set the user distribution for the first human activity in a BPD as "last user" ("last user in lane" for older versions of the product), it has a special meaning to the system that indicates that the task should be immediately assigned the user that started the process and the first coach be immediately displayed (assuming the user has the permissions to that activity, and the BPD is able to immediately flow to that activity).
In theory, this is documented here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v8r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wbpm.main.doc%2Fic-homepage-bpm.html under "last user", but the docs are very confusing. Even to me, and I know what it is supposed to be saying.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to make the user to flow human tasks without return to his/her inbox in**

> process portal

`so you should do from process designer two things`

- first put the assignment to be last user in the lane
- and the second make true on check box on every task in the land you
  want to follow automatically to next task.